# Prevent script from executing based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to prevent the following Javascript from executing for screens that are smaller than 769px. I am a total Javascript newbie, this script is from a Codrops tutorial on how to animate a header on scroll. I have made a small modification that allows me to use images. The original script was for text elements only. Here is the slightly modified script in its entirety.

```
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

var docElem = document.documentElement,
    header = document.querySelector( '.header-outer' ),
    logo = document.querySelector( '.logo' )
    didScroll = false,
    changeHeaderOn = 300;




function init() {
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
        if( !didScroll ) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
        }
    }, false );
}



    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if  ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
            classie.add( header, 'header-shrink' );
            classie.add( logo, 'logo-shrink' );
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( header, 'header-shrink' );
            classie.remove( logo, 'logo-shrink' );
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }



function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
}

init();

})();
```

I did see someone else on StackOverflow ask a similar question, but the solution (`if ($(window).width() > 768) {`) that was given to him hasn't worked for me so far, I am sure that I am applying it incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `$(window).width()` is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). jQuery is a JavaScript library. If you’re not using it, then that code wouldn’t do anything.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite but throwing a `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: yes, very true: that’s what it would do.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Paul, I will try Niall's suggestion and see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason

```
$(window).width()
```

isn't working for you is because it uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com), which you're not using it seems.

Instead use:

```
window.innerWidth
```

So, do this:

```
if  ( sy >= changeHeaderOn && window.innerWidth > 768  ) {
    classie.add( header, 'header-shrink' );
    classie.add( logo, 'logo-shrink' );
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is quite embarrassing, I apologize for the oversight, I will try your suggestion thank you :)

Comment: Niall, please excuse my newbieness, I have tried your suggestion, but I can't seem to make it work, the header and logo are still being resized at sizes below 768px. How would you apply it to the above script?

Comment: @Nillansan so you basically don't want to run `classie.add( header, 'header-shrink' );
            classie.add( logo, 'logo-shrink' );` if the width is less than 768 right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I don't want the header to animate when the width is less than 768px.

Comment: @Nillansan I've updated my answer, that will only execute them lines if the width of the screen is greater than 768. If it is smaller, it'll try to remove them, but they won't be there in the first place so it is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Try this js,

```
window.outerWidth,
```

You can check for all window associated objects via console.log(window).